# How to filter the list using another list?

Tags: c#, linq

We have the following list of Employees.

```
List<Employee> EmployeeList =new List<Employee>();
EmployeeList.Add(new Employee{ Id=101, Name="XYZ" });
EmployeeList.Add(new Employee{ Id=102, Name="QRS" });
EmployeeList.Add(new Employee{ Id=103, Name="ABC" });
EmployeeList.Add(new Employee{ Id=1101, Name="DEF" });
```

And List of Selected Employee Id's as below.

```
List<long> selectedEmployeeIds={ 101,103 };
```

We wants to filter the selected Employees from the above EmployeeList. We tried using contains as below but its fetching 3 records as 101,102,1101.

```
var selectedEmployees= (from record in EmployeeList where selectedEmployeeIds.Contains(record.Id.ToString()) select record).ToList(); // returning 3 records.
```

Could any one help us to get only the Employees 101,103.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we got the result for the above query as,

```
List<Employee> filteredRecords = (from a in EmployeeList join b in selectedEmployeeIds on a.ID equals b select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `ToString()`, Use [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx), which will work with any datatype, not just strings. Your current code should give an error since `selectedEmployeeIds` is of type `long` and your are checking it against `string`.

```
var selectedEmployees= (from record in EmployeeList 
                       where selectedEmployeeIds.Contains(record.Id) 
                       select record).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry. I am afraid, Contains() only accepts char or string. Any other possibilities like join table.

Comment: @Sravan, no it does not , try the above code, if your `record.Id` is of type long, this code should work.

Comment: @Sravan, also this `selectedEmployeeIds.Contains(101)` would return true for your example code